# Rails - How to add an object to a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I would like to make something like this:

```
@profiles
#(I think in Java, so I have declared an @profiles variable there! I know it's probably wrong!)
@users.each do |user|
  profile = Profile.find(params[user.id])
  @profiles.add(profile)
end
```

The user and profile have a one-to-one relationship.

user has one profile, 
profile belongs to user

Comment: You haven't "declared" an `@profiles` variable there. You've just tried to look up that instance variable, and since it doesn't exist, the line evaluates to `nil`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initialize the array.

```
@profiles = []
@users.each do |user|
  profile = Profile.find(params[user.id])
  @profiles << profile if profile
end
```

If you have a relationship, you should be able to just say:

```
@profiles = []
@users.each do |user|
  profile = user.profile
  @profiles << profile if profile
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` will already return a collection.

In this case, however, it looks more like you should have a codified relationship:

```
class User
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Info: [has_one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association), [belongs_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs_to-association)

Comment: that is exactly what I have, and I'm trying to get a collection of Profiles based on a collection of User IDs where the user.id is profile.user_id

Comment: @spuriosity If that's what you have, why didn't you show it? How are you saving the user's profile? Why are you re-building the association when Rails gives it to you for free?

Comment: I'm using  where('user_id LIKE ?', "%#{search}%") to search (in the profile obj), but this is obviously searching ids in the profile table. I need to search through the table of users associated with the profiles, not through the profiles table. Trying to figure out a workaround.

Comment: @spuriosity Why? If the relationship is set up correctly, this functionality is automatic.

Comment: automatic, yes, but i don't know the syntax to replace the  where('user_id LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"), or rather, I don't know how to search the related table using this syntax

Comment: @spuriosity `user.profile`. That's it. You're trying to replace existing Rails functionality--I'm trying to understand *why*, otherwise answering the question is... problematic.

Comment: @DavidNewton, you have misunderstood I think. I am not trying purposefully to overwrite, just to work around my knowledge deficiency. user.profile is not what I'm trying to do. If I could make up syntax, my representation of this would be profile.user.name LIKE ?, but that's not the way the relationships are set up. I need to search through the parent table.

Comment: @spuriosity Perhaps I *have* misunderstood. If a user has-a profile, why are you trying to search at *all*?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5948/discussion-between-spuriosity-and-dave-newton)

Comment: @spuriosity You should change the question to fix your knowledge deficiency rather than to ask for help writing a workaround for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this in you models

```
class User
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And this in your Profile migration

```
t.integer :user_id
```

You can find the profiles like this

```
@profiles = Profile.all
```

and then in your views

```
<% @profiles.each do |profile| %>

<%= profile.user.name %>

<%end%>
```

**update**

If you have

where('user_id LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")

try this models/user.rb.

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('name LIKE ? ', "%#{search}%" )
    else
      scoped
    end
end
```

In controller:

@users = User.search(params[:search])

and then in your views

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>

<%= user.profile.name %>

<%end%>
```

[A Guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: I have this: where('user_id LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"), and what I need is to search through the .name attribute of the user at that user_id

Comment: I made an update on the answer. I'll take a closer look tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the following:

replace

```
 @profiles.add(profile)
```

with

```
 @profiles << profile
```

The << operator add the element on the right to the array on the left.